# error message, node project installation on server?

Tags: node.js, server

Im trying to start my node project on my node server but I keep getting a error message, the server is ready to use node, I already have some other projects installed on it but this I can't understand. Can anyone understand this error message?

```
 events.js:69
    throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event
                   ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at errnoException (net.js:850:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:995:14)
    at listen (net.js:1022:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1071:5)
    at Function.app.listen (/srv/www/ikonset.com/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:531:24)
```

Comment: `EADDRINUSE` means there's another process already listening on that port.

Answer (score 1):

The error `EADDRINUSE` means you already have a process bound to the port you're trying to listen on (3000 or whatever). What you should do is first STOP your other process on that port, then restart your Node app.